# How to adjust wingpanel's height

Tags: wingpanel

is there a way to decrease the wingpanel's height? 
I have tried looking into `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` and
`/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css` but i cant really find anything in there.

Answer (score 1):

I used to modify the shadow of wingpanel in the older version never needed in newer version, you can look that one in apps.css.

If you want some serious modification just install below:

`sudo apt-get install wingpanel-slim elementary-tweaks`

once install go to `System settings` and look for `Tweaks`. That should help you.

Comment: wingpanel-slim is not in the official repos